# Filter for column value and set its other column to an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df such as

```
Letter | Stats
  B       0
  B       1
  C       22
  B       0
  C       0
  B       3
```

How can I filter for a value in the Letter column and also then convert the stats column for that value into an array?

Basically want to filter for B and convert the Stats column to an array, Thanks!

Comment: It would just be array([0,1,0,3]) - all the values in the stats column as an array filtered for B for Letter column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# function received, dataframe and letter as parameter
# return stats values as list for the passed Letter
def grp(df, letter):
    return df.loc[df['Letter'].eq(letter)]['Stats'].values.tolist()

# pass the dataframe, and the letter 
result=grp(df,'B')
print(result)

[0, 1, 0, 3]
```

data used

```
data ={'Letter': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'B'},
 'Stats': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 22, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 3}}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I believe that solution proposed by @Naveed is enough for this problem one little extension could be suggested.

If you would like to get result as an pandas series and obtain some statistic for the series:

```
data ={'Letter': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'B'},
 'Stats': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 22, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 3}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

letter = 'B'
ser = pd.Series(name=letter, data=df.loc[df['Letter'].eq(letter)]['Stats'].values)
```

`print(f"Max value: {ser.max()} | Min value: {ser.min()} | Median value: {ser.median()}")` etc.

Output:
`Max value: 3 | Min value: 0 | Median value: 0.5`